# code igniter passing database session_id in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get Uploadify working with code igniter however am having the same problem as everyone with a new session being created for "ShockWave Flash" instead of picking up the already created session.

I have the following setttings set

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

The Code Igniter session table is like so
WITH BROWSER

```
   session_id: 73b05af777af0e6a56e7bbba8f9714f6
   ip_address: 127.0.0.1
   user_agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/53
last_activity: 1310341663
    user_data: a:6:{s:5:"email";s:32:"test@hotmail.com"}
```

WITH UPLOADIFY

```
   session_id: d39bce3d9c734081379b286449cf56ce
   ip_address: 127.0.0.1
   user_agent: Shockwave Flash
last_activity: 1310341167
    user_data:
```

I'm trying to hack this and add the browser session_id as a get to the php like so so when uploadify submits I can retrieve user session data given the session id.

```
              $(document).ready(function() {   
                $('#uploadify').uploadify({  
                  'uploader'  : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',   
                  'script'    : '/index.php/upload/uploadify/'.$this->session->userdata('session_id').'',
```

My question is:
1) is it bad that I am showing the session_id publicly in the source, is that session_id available regardless even if I don't do this?
2) On the "upload" controller, how can I essentially "load" that session_id or get data out from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The only way that would pose a problem is if you're encrypting the session_id cookie -- otherwise, you're not giving the user any more real data. (So, yes, in most cases, they can get that data anyway)
2. You will need to overwrite `sess_read()` or `__construct` in your `MY_Session` class to look at a custom variable or you could modify the cookie

Basically this:

```
public function __construct( $id )
{
   // a hack, but you need a hack
   $_COOKIE[ $this->sess_cookie_name ] = $id;
   parent::__construct();
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot cwallenpoole! So I actually am encrypting the session cookie so the cookie is encrypted to the user, maybe I can just do some custom encryption on my session_id to sort of keep it safe to the public. I will try the above code tonight, thanks!

Comment: Couple questions 1) If I modify the constructor of the session class like shown above, how do I specify that input $id? What is the proper flow. 2) I tried to simply modify the sess_read() function and manually call it with my session id parameter and technically this works but the problem is sess_read gets called twice, once automatically for uploadify and a second time when I manually call it at the top of my controller so I think I really need to modify the constructor. 3) How do you extend code igniter libraries? It doesn't seem to be the same as for system classes...

Comment: 1. $this->load->library( 'session', $id ); 2. If you're manually setting the session_id, it shouldn't matter how often you call it. Is there an error? 3. Create a file under application/libraries called MY_Session.php. Place the class MY_Session inside it and have it subclass CI_Session

Comment: You need a semicolon at the end of the line