# Setting Session_id in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, session, codeigniter

In standard PHP i can set the session ID by following:

```
$my_session_id = $_GET['session_id']; //gets the session ID successfully
session_id($my_session_id);   //sets the session with my session_id
session_start();  //starts session.
```

How can I do same with the CodeIgniter? I am trying following:

```
$my_session_id = $_GET['session_id']; //gets the session ID successfully
$this->session->userdata('session_id', $my_session_id); //it won't set the session with my id.
print_r($this->session->userdata);
```

Am i making some mistake? Please help me as I have wasted several hours in this problem. If there is some issue with CodeIgniter Session class, can I use the standard PHP code to start session? I have tried to place the standard code in CodeIgniter as well, but it still does not set the session_id. I have also set `$config['sess_match_useragent']    = FALSE;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hack I just suggested on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644563/code-igniter-passing-database-session-id-in-view/6655379#6655379). Place this in the `__construct` of `MY_Session` (untested and will not work with encryption)

```
public function __construct()
{
   if( isset( $_GET['session_id'] ) ) 
        $_COOKIE[ $this->sess_cookie_name ] = $_GET['session_id'];
   // Session now looks up $_COOKIE[ 'session_id' ] to get the session_id
   parent::__construct()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I dont have MY_Session file, do i need to create MY_Session.php file in the libraries folder of CodeIgniter or in Core folder? After I have created and posted this code, how i will call the MY_Session? (Sorry I'm new to CodeIgniter or any framework)

Comment: If you place a MY_Session.php file in your library folder, it will be used instead of CI_Session

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't need to do this, codeigniter does it all for you.

If you wish to get the session id you can do so by calling:

```
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
```

However you can work around it: ( Note this post is 3 years old and I'm unsure if it's still necessary )

http://mumrah.net/2008/06/codeigniter-session-id/

Answer (score 0):

use this for setting session_id in codeigniter:

```
$this->session->set_userdata( array('session_id', $your_session_id) );
```

and

```
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
```

for reading it out again.

Comment: It will set my session id with `session_id [1]` , even i have placed this in previous line: `$this->session->unset_userdata('session_id');`

Answer (score 0):

You should always start your session before modifying any session variables.

I believe to start the CodeIgniter session you can do the following;

```
$this->load->library('session');
$my_session_id = $_GET['session_id']; //gets the session ID successfully
$this->session->userdata('session_id', $my_session_id); //it won't set the session with my id.
print_r($this->session->userdata);
```

Comment: Thanks, but im autoloading the session library.

Comment: In CI3, getting the session ID is done by calling session_id();