# codeigniter session why gen auto?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

result $member form db
I set

```
$sess['session_id']=$rs['user_id'];
$sess['session_name']=$rs['user_username'];
$this->session->set_userdata($sess);
```

my receive

```
$this->session->userdata('session_id') = 1
$this->session->userdata('user_username') = admin
```

but for a moment i see that

```
$this->session->userdata('session_id') = 700336412dd230af450558b92a728b59
```

is wrong

```
$this->session->userdata('user_username') = admin
```

why session_id (num)  change auto ?

**THIS MY CONFIG config.php**

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting Session\_id in CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656491/setting-session-id-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to change session data use:

`$this->session->set_userdata('session_name', $session_value);`

When you want to get the session use:

`$session_value = $this->session->userdata('session_name');`

More details, read [userguide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Also don't use variable name like: `session_id`